# Call VB program from Java

Tags: java, vb.net, vb6

I was wondering if someone could tell me the best way to call a Visual Basic program from Java.  I have a few VB applications that I want to run from a Java application that I'm building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ProcessBuilder.start()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) or the older [Runtime.exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) to launch processes. This information is available in the [Java SE docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/reference/index.jsp).

Comment: JJO, fixed capitalization and provided the link for Runtime.exec(). +1.